# Possible to mix-and-match runtimes in Azure Durable Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Basically I'd like to have a durable orchestrator function written in one language, but have it call out to at least one task function in another language. Obviously they would need to be in different runtimes, and thus different function projects/apps. Is this possible? I could not find a straight answer in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

When the Function Host is started, it will identify the Language Runtime and its worker process will be called by the Script Host, then the functions (trigger) get invoked.

[image]

This is how Azure Functions runs in the backend. It can't be possible to merge two different languages of Functions in a Single Azure Function App because, as per the design, the function is executed by its language runtime workers.

- For dotnet --> azure-functions-dotnet-worker
- For python --> Azure-functions-python-worker
- For PowerShell -->Azure-functions-PowerShell-worker

> Obviously they would need to be in different runtimes, and thus different function projects/apps.

Yes, it is possible. But you can separate Azure Function Apps for the languages you need and call them using Http Triggers or the Web hooks.

This is similar to making HTTP Requests and Responses between two Function Apps of different languages.

For more information on making the Http calls between two different Function Apps, refer [Azure Functions Webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#webhooks) by Microsoft.

Comment: Sure, but I'm still not sure if I can mix-and-match runtimes when using Azure _Durable_ Functions.